# sudo authorizeUpgrade return invalid?

Tags: parachain, extrinsic, runtime-upgrade, extrinsicstatus

What is sudo invalid mean? This error happened when I did a parachain authorizeUpgrade. I had upgrade success many times in some way. But this is the first time I got this error.

Is it mean code invalid or sign invalid or else?

More details below

[image]

**console**

signAndSend: status :: {"events":[],"status":{"invalid":null},"txHash":"0xd0a70f19e64fe8748459eb0e4b5630a98ab73210742c74ca09c192c7f0032eeb"}

[image]

Trace log report **Invalid transaction: Extrinsic is not valid: TransactionValidityError::Invalid(InvalidTransaction::Stale)**

```
/data/logs/collator-01.log.3:2022-05-21 17:33:36.716 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker sc_basic_authorship::basic_authorship: [Parachain] [0x64fb84d0108e9afffdb9a33834002ba5c083091bfbead8ff3699216220df1628] Pushing to the block.
/data/logs/collator-01.log.3:2022-05-21 17:33:36.723 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] [0x64fb84d0108e9afffdb9a33834002ba5c083091bfbead8ff3699216220df1628] Reported as invalid. Will skip sub-chains while iterating.
/data/logs/collator-01.log.3:2022-05-21 17:33:36.725 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker sc_basic_authorship::basic_authorship: [Parachain] [0x64fb84d0108e9afffdb9a33834002ba5c083091bfbead8ff3699216220df1628] Invalid transaction: Extrinsic is not valid: TransactionValidityError::Invalid(InvalidTransaction::Stale)
/data/logs/collator-01.log.3:2022-05-21 17:33:36.728 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] Removing invalid transactions: [0x64fb84d0108e9afffdb9a33834002ba5c083091bfbead8ff3699216220df1628]
/data/logs/collator-01.log.3:2022-05-21 17:33:36.728 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] [0x64fb84d0108e9afffdb9a33834002ba5c083091bfbead8ff3699216220df1628] Removed as part of the subtree.
/data/logs/collator-01.log.3:2022-05-21 17:33:36.728 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] Removed invalid transactions: [Transaction { hash: 0x64fb84d0108e9afffdb9a33834002ba5c083091bfbead8ff3699216220df1628, priority: 262162175625036921, valid_till: 101592, bytes: 142, propagate: true, source: TransactionSource::External, requires: [], provides: [56d94ef121f261199437d186da47e5c335db65907cb556842d31c9fe6907034259000000], data: 840056d94ef121f261199437d186da47e5c335db65907cb556842d31c9fe69070342016412f04bfa069ee674c8f311ffa1e735c01138329773ef8eaab64b1d61cf426a32f7bbcaab5cca9fd8686656b46c7fe014c9a59bb5ef6193a13dfcaf80070280940165010004000102e2a1130413b2c6d0cf89e0f8d1c0383bc8a26350d359267ef957a613ba4889f0}]
/data/logs/collator-01.log.3:2022-05-21 17:33:36.728 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] [0x64fb84d0108e9afffdb9a33834002ba5c083091bfbead8ff3699216220df1628] Extrinsic invalid
/data/logs/collator-01.log.4:2022-05-21 17:33:24.686 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] Updated revalidation queue at 101563. Transactions: {0x64fb84d0108e9afffdb9a33834002ba5c083091bfbead8ff3699216220df1628: 101563}
/data/logs/collator-01.log.4:2022-05-21 17:33:25.141 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] [0x64fb84d0108e9afffdb9a33834002ba5c083091bfbead8ff3699216220df1628] Removed as part of the subtree.
/data/logs/collator-01.log.4:2022-05-21 17:33:25.202 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] [0x64fb84d0108e9afffdb9a33834002ba5c083091bfbead8ff3699216220df1628] WaitingTransaction { imported_at: Instant { tv_sec: 3121250, tv_nsec: 456894293 }, transaction: Transaction { hash: 0x64fb84d0108e9afffdb9a33834002ba5c083091bfbead8ff3699216220df1628, priority: 262162175625036921, valid_till: 101592, bytes: 142, propagate: true, source: TransactionSource::External, requires: [], provides: [56d94ef121f261199437d186da47e5c335db65907cb556842d31c9fe6907034259000000], data: 840056d94ef121f261199437d186da47e5c335db65907cb556842d31c9fe69070342016412f04bfa069ee674c8f311ffa1e735c01138329773ef8eaab64b1d61cf426a32f7bbcaab5cca9fd8686656b46c7fe014c9a59bb5ef6193a13dfcaf80070280940165010004000102e2a1130413b2c6d0cf89e0f8d1c0383bc8a26350d359267ef957a613ba4889f0}, missing_tags: {}}
/data/logs/collator-01.log.4:2022-05-21 17:33:25.202 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] [0x64fb84d0108e9afffdb9a33834002ba5c083091bfbead8ff3699216220df1628] Importing to ready
/data/logs/collator-01.log.5:2022-05-21 17:33:15.390 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [0x64fb84d0108e9afffdb9a33834002ba5c083091bfbead8ff3699216220df1628] WaitingTransaction { imported_at: Instant { tv_sec: 3121240, tv_nsec: 645564877 }, transaction: Transaction { hash: 0x64fb84d0108e9afffdb9a33834002ba5c083091bfbead8ff3699216220df1628, priority: 262162175625036921, valid_till: 101592, bytes: 142, propagate: true, source: TransactionSource::External, requires: [], provides: [56d94ef121f261199437d186da47e5c335db65907cb556842d31c9fe6907034259000000], data: 840056d94ef121f261199437d186da47e5c335db65907cb556842d31c9fe69070342016412f04bfa069ee674c8f311ffa1e735c01138329773ef8eaab64b1d61cf426a32f7bbcaab5cca9fd8686656b46c7fe014c9a59bb5ef6193a13dfcaf80070280940165010004000102e2a1130413b2c6d0cf89e0f8d1c0383bc8a26350d359267ef957a613ba4889f0}, missing_tags: {}}
/data/logs/collator-01.log.5:2022-05-21 17:33:15.391 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [0x64fb84d0108e9afffdb9a33834002ba5c083091bfbead8ff3699216220df1628] Importing to ready
/data/logs/collator-01.log.5:2022-05-21 17:33:15.391 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [0x64fb84d0108e9afffdb9a33834002ba5c083091bfbead8ff3699216220df1628] Ready (replaced with None)
/data/logs/collator-01.log.5:2022-05-21 17:33:15.391 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker sync: [Parachain] Propagating transaction [0x64fb84d0108e9afffdb9a33834002ba5c083091bfbead8ff3699216220df1628]
/data/logs/collator-01.log.5:2022-05-21 17:33:15.391 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] [0x64fb84d0108e9afffdb9a33834002ba5c083091bfbead8ff3699216220df1628] Broadcasted
```

Comment: `InvalidTransaction::Stale` points that the transaction is outdated, which can be caused by the nonce being too low.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Stale` means that another/newer transaction with a higher nonce has already been processed.

You can find the explicit enum [entry here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/ded44948e2d5a398abcb4e342b0513cb690961bb/primitives/runtime/src/transaction_validity.rs#L46-L47) in the actual transaction pool code.